# Snapdeal Selenium automation for email and next button for google sign in

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Snapdeal  when I hover to Sign In and click login  , it is opening signup dialog box
and when I try to  login in  and click google Sign in, it is clicking, email dialog box is opening, but is not finding the element for email textbox and it is not accepting any value and it is also not finding  element for next button. Iam using selenium java with cucumber framework.

```
 @When("The user  selects that particular account linked with snapdeal")
    public void the_user_selects_that_particular_account_linked_with_snapdeal() {
    WebElement Email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input"));
       Email.sendKeys("ap3570801@gmail.com");
    
    l1=new LoginPojo();
            btnClick(l1.getNext());
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Next']")
    private WebElement Next;
    public WebElement getNext() {
    return Next;
    }
```

Comment: probably you are not in the correct iframe.

Comment: How do we find that

Comment: Email textfield in gmail is in iframe? Iam getting problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gmail** input fields are in new windows. You need to switch to windows like this

```
   // on clicking on google Sign in button, you need to switch like this :- 
   ArrayList<String> allWindowsHandles = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
   driver.switchTo().window(allWindowsHandles.get(1));
   
   // here your code, to send keys to input
```